# Android TextView not center aligned when visited back from other activity?

Tags: android

Ok I have a very weird issue that I never faced before. So I have a tableLayout with 2 columns inside. Here is the result for first launching the activity:

[image]

After I navigate to other activity and come back to this activity, here is the result:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <LinearLayout 
            android:background="#FF4545"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1" />

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1.1" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:background="#70FF42"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="2" />

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="2.1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Can anyone advise me what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Updated your layout, see if it works for you

```
  <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FF4545"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="1.1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#70FF42"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="2" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="2.1" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that the **table layout** is within a **linear layout** and it will get displayed correctly

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is a sample of such [layout](http://androidthon.info/implementing-android-toast/)